# Can not install elementary OS alongside Windows

Tags: release-juno, software-installation

I used rufus to burn a usb to make it into a bootable usb for elementary OS 5.0 Juno with which I was hoping to be able to dual boot elementary OS 5.0 Juno with my already existing windows 10. However, when I boot into the usb and select Install elementary OS it show a screen where it shows  some sort of error, something about "couldn't read" for like 2 seconds and goes away then nothing happens. I tried the other options as well but nothing worked. Do you know what I should do?

Comment: That destroyed my USB

Answer (score 1):

I used usb-startup-creator available in xubuntu to create an install-usb for elementary os this week. Worked perfectly!

Or maybe check the bios/uefi/secureboot settings of the laptop. Sometimes laptops are protected to prevent installing other os's than windows...

Comment: Like @giel mentioned, I'd check the BIOS/UEFI/Secure Boot options, but make sure that you understand the implications of switching the settings around for your particular device, and make sure you're confident you know how to switch it back to the original settings before making a change—just in case you run in to problems booting back into your Windows environment post-changes.  

Since elementaryOS is built on Ubuntu, the latest versions do support devices with UEFI and Secure Boot enabled, so in theory I think most modern devices should work out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

Download the iso directly from Elementary OS website. Get rid of the rufus. Download balena etcher, install it and run it to make bootable stick using the usb drive and downloaded iso file. Turn off fast boot in power management in Windows. Make in Windows disk manager empty space for Elementary OS, but do not format it. During the installation just select this empty space to tell Elementary OS to install there. So as far as I remember it is not the first automated installation, not the third option with the manual partitioning but the second which allows to install Elementary OS alongside with Windows.

Comment: Sometimes I have issues with different USB boot disk creation tools, so it's good to be familiar with various options such as Rufus, UNetbootin, Universal USB Installer, balentaEtcher, etc.)
I agree with @Sysadmin, definitely give balentaEtcher a try if you haven't already. Lately, I've had the most consistent success with it. https://www.balena.io/etcher/

Answer (score 0):

check the integrity of the ISO you downloaded, it could be that your elementary ISO is corrupted or maybe your USB is faulty

Comment: I have tried that